# Jenkins: Execute shell script at end of job regardless of result

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I’m wanting to run an HTTP POST request at the end of a Jenkins job regardless of whether it failed or was aborted early. I planned to do this using a simple Curl command.

I know this is possible with the [Post build task plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuild-task/).
However, I believe, it saves the whole console to RAM for text comparisons, which not only do I not need, but will most likely cause OOM exceptions on our master.

Also, I don’t see any documentation for the plubin to try test this using a Jenkins script only in the UI.
Does anyone have any alternatives or a way to call `postbuild-task` within a Jenkins file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this with a simple try finally block since my original code didnt use jenkins pipelines

Answer (score 0):

You can use post build step. Add this post section

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage(""){
      steps {
        script {
    
        }
      }
    }
  }
  post { #---------------This block
    always {
      script {
        your stuff which you want execute no matter what
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a post block after the stages

```
post {
    success {
      //Success block
    }

    unstable {
      //unstable block
    }

    failure {
      //Failure block
    }

    always {
      //This block will always be executed regardless of the build outcome
      echo "Build completed with status: ${currentBuild.result}"
    }
}
```

**Standard flow sample:**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("1") {
            }
        stage("2") {
            }
         ....
       }
  post {
    always {
           //This block will always be executed
           }
       }
}
```